# Ractive / Moustache Template for Head Tag

Tags: templates, mustache, ractivejs

I have been searching for this all over, but can not find an answer or example.

Can a Ractive template be used to construct head elements that are consistant across pages, and can that be loaded from a separate file?

For example: all html, head, and title tag info is loaded via a referencable template from an external file into an index page.
    +html+
    +head+
    +title+
    +/title+
    +/head+

And if so, how do you do it?  As I try to wrap my head around it, jquery and ractive.js would need to load.  Is there a different/better solution?

Comment: Why would you replace the head tag? I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here. Unless you're doing server-side rendering, that I understand.

Comment: I'm looking to setup templates like I can with php - where I can just include a php file that contains all of the header information.  I have been trying to see if I can do it with a JS templating solution, but they require including the js file in the head - so I wasn't sure you could do it?  I think I might instead use a router framework and then just create an index.html template file.

Comment: If you render the html on the server this could be solved with a component.

Comment: So you're doing server-side rendering then? Best if you describe your situation in detail before people close this for being too broad or unclear.

Comment: Thanks PEtter and Joseph the Dreams for the suggestion.  I have not heard of this (as I'm just delving into this), so I will look into that as a better solution to templating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. But it's not practical and it raises other issues.

Here's a basic implementation that shows how `<head>` can be templated but without concentrating on putting the template in an external file. This works for me in Chrome and IE.

```
<html>

<head id="output"></head>
<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ractive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ractive = new Ractive({
        template: "#template",
        el: "#output",
        data: {
            title: "This is the title"
        }
    });
</script>

<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

You'll run into problems with this approach because the head elements won't be loaded until after the page has loaded and Ractive kicks in. This may cause the following problems:

- Search engines might not be able to read the page title and meta tags
- Any javascript you need to load into `<head>` may not work (I tried some simple examples and was able to get the javascript to run but it failed to reference any elements in the body. Maybe it's a context issue and maybe Ractive has support to overcome this but this is an area I'm unfamiliar with.)
- If you require valid HTML, this probably won't work for you because script tags can't be direct children of `<html>`, and `<head>` is supposed to have `<title>` as a direct child.

You're better off using a server-side solution to template `<head>`.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for this.  I was able to get it to work - but your points about potential problems are issues I had not considered and would be hugely detrimental - like not being able to reference elements in the body.  I have not heard of server-side rendering.  I will look into that as a potential solution.  Thank you for your help and support!